# next() not helping 3rd element on scrollTop()

Tags: jquery

I've got 3 DIVs and what I am trying to do is if user scrolls bottom those DIVs *one after another* get appeared and if he scrolls top they'd get disappear. First 2 DIVs are working fine but the 3rd one is NOT.

This is what I tried :

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 100) {
        $("#one").fadeIn(5000);
        $('#two').next().fadeIn(5000);
        $('#three').next().fadeIn(5000); 
    }
});
$(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() < 100) {
        $("#one").fadeOut(10);
        $('#two').next().fadeOut(10);
        $('#three').next().fadeOut(10);
    }
});
```

And [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/EqYsy/15/) is the sample.

Any correction or suggestion ?

Comment: just remove .next() Also, instead of hiding the divs, I'd animate their opacity to 0 so that the page dimensions remain the same. As it is, the scrollbar changes size and that's really confusing. http://jsfiddle.net/EqYsy/16/

Comment: @frenchie, that was the next issue I was thinking of. I'd just try that on jsfiddle. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `next()` is selecting the next `div` instead of the one you want so in effect you are saying `one` fade in, `three` fade in, and the thing after `three` fade in. Same with out. Remove all of the `.next()` and see if it does what you want.

Edit:
You said that you wanted them to appear as you scrolled to them, you could try using [jQuery Waypoints](http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/). An example would be http://jsfiddle.net/EqYsy/28/

```
$('.fadeClass').waypoint(function(direction){
  if(direction == "down")
    $(this).animate({opacity:1}, 5000);
  else if(direction == "up")
    $(this).animate({opacity:0}, 1000);
},{offset:500});
```

Comment: Although I'd tried that, that did not work first. But is there a better technique than what I've done ( 3 times using fadeIn() )!!!

Comment: @John: yes, there's another way of doing it: you can simply wrap the 3 divs inside another div and just do the effect with the wrapper div.

Comment: @John There are lots of ways you could do it, you could give them all a class, or you could select them all at once like `$('#one').nextAll('p').addBack().fadeIn(5000);` but it really all comes down to what you want to do.

Comment: @frenchie, They are already in a wrapper DIV. but what technique? what function ? next() ?

Comment: @BearFist, I tried what you said. but no result. would you check out the code?

Comment: @BearFist, I appreciate the time you've already given me. And maybe I didn't mention in my question. If "one" is gallery and "two" a conatct form, I want each to appear IF the scrollbar comes to them rather than just scrolling bottom for 100px.

Comment: @John I updated with an example of using the `jQuery Waypoints` plugin. It might help you do what you want to do.

Comment: I'm trying to overcome a strange conflict and apply that.

Answer (score 1):

Try [this](http://jsfiddle.net/EqYsy/21/):

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 100) {
        $("#one").fadeIn(5000).next().fadeIn(5000).next().fadeIn(5000); 
    }
});
$(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() < 100) {
        $("#one").fadeOut(10).next().fadeOut(10).next().fadeOut(10);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the problem with `.next()`, I'd rewrite your code like that:

```
$(window).scroll(function () {

    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 100) {

        $('#test').animate({opacity:1}, 5000);

    } else {

        $('#test').stop(true, false).css({'opacity':0});
    } 
});
```

I think it looks easier and more understandable. And for the HTML, I'd add a wrapper (here called test) just to reduce the code size. The jsFiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/EqYsy/26/)

Comment: Really thank you for giving time :) I checked that out and yes, scrollbar resizing is gone.